# Express 4 Error Handling Middleware Not Being Hit

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express 4 I'm struggling to get custom error handling middleware to work.

I'm using the NPM package express-async-errors to handle async errors, but my error handler isn't being hit for async or synchronous calls.

Routes defined like this in their own file:

```
module.exports.set = (app, apiVersion) => {
  app.get(
    `${apiVersion}/User/iscool`, UserTest.TheUserTestWorks,
  );

  app.get(
    `${apiVersion}/User/error`, UserTest.TheUserTestThrowAnErrorSynchronously,
  );

  app.get(
    `${apiVersion}/User/AsyncError`, UserTest.TheUserTestThrowAnErrorAsync,
  );
};
```

And added in index.js like this:

```
fs.readdir("./routers", (err, routes) => {
  routes.map((route) => {
    const module = require(`./routers/${route.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")}`);
    module.set(app, apiVersion);
    return route;
  });
  return true;
});
```

Middleware defined like this:

```
const Sentry = require("@sentry/node");

function genericExceptionHandlerMiddleware(err, req, res, next) {
  Sentry.captureException(err);
  res.status(500).send("An unknown error occurred");
  next(err);
}

module.exports = genericExceptionHandlerMiddleware;
```

And added like this at the bottom of Index.js immediately before module.exports = app:

```
app.use(genericExceptionHandlerMiddleware);
```

It does work however if I add the app.use inside the file where the routes listed above are defined, however I want this to apply to all routes.

As far as I can tell there's no other middleware that would be swallowing the exception.

The process console shows the exception being hit when it's added in index.js but doesn't do seem to run the code (if I add a console.log, it's not logged). It does log when added to the end of the file with the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly simple what the issue was - the function fs.readdir is async, so even though the app.use was called at the end it obviously wasn't being run after the various routers had been setup.